# Golang SQL error expected 0 arguments got 3

Tags: sql, go

I'm using `github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb` library and driver but getting an error `sql: expected 0 arguments, got 3 exit status 1` when inserting new row.

```
tsql := "INSERT INTO Uploads (Fname, Fsize, Ftype) VALUES (@Fname, @Fsize, @Ftype );"
fmt.Printf("tsql = %s\n", tsql)

//Execute non-query with named parameters
res, err := db.ExecContext(
    ctx,
    tsql,
    sql.Named("Fname", fname),
    sql.Named("Fsize", fsize),
    sql.Named("Ftype", ftype))

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(" AddRow_v1() -> Error creating new row: " + err.Error())
    return -1, err
}
```

Comment: I this you have to call dB.QueryContext not dB.ExecContext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue might be related to driver name used in the connection string.
I've tried the same query with yours, the record is created without any errors.

I believe that you are currently using mssql in connection string; sql.Open("mssql", conn) (This issue has already been discussed in https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/issues/594#issuecomment-809922317)

If you try again by replacing "mssql" to "sqlserver", the problem should be solved.